# Encryption of file using gpg failed

Tags: unix, gnupg

I am extracting data to .psv files through a script. These .psv files have to be encrypted and SFTPed to antoher server location. But the extracted psv files are not getting encrypted. It is throwing the following error:

gpg: Invalid option "--trust-model"

I am using the following command

`gpg -r 'abc@def.com' --encrypt --trust-model always $File_Name`

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the `--trust-model always` option myself, but I think you need to specify the file name last (or at least following the `--encrypt` option).  So, try this:

```
gpg -r 'abc@def.com' --trust-model always --encrypt $File_Name
```

I have seen, but never personally used the `--always-trust` option, so here's another thing you can try:

```
gpg -r 'abc@def.com' --always-trust --encrypt $File_Name
```

I always add "trust" to every key I add to my ring so I'm not familiar with either of these options.